# inner use of cursor outside declare block

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have to use a cursor inside a particular block which contains query with `WHERE` clause getting parameters dynamically...

Therefore how to use a cursor without declaring in `DECLARE` block.

(I can't use nested cursors - am looking for examples).

Comment: Not sure, why you need a cursor in the first place, Can you post some code and explain what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Also, after adding some code as Sudipta suggested, please specify if MySQL or Oracle. Huge difference in what is possible and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ***Implicit Cursor*** that uses a local parameter to your procedure. Here is how it looks like:

```
declare 
  v_parm varchar2(3) := 'Z';
begin
-- FIRST LOOP will display all objects owned by Z
  for x in ( select * from all_objects where owner=v_parm) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(x.object_name);
  end loop;
-- SECOND LOOP will display all objects owned by SYS until 100 is reached
--     (that would be a huge bunch otherwise!)
  v_parm := 'SYS';
  for x in ( select * from all_objects where owner=v_parm and rowid < 100) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(x.object_name);
  end loop;  
end;
/
```